# Does Synchronized retain lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Consider the code:

```
class Account {
  private int balance=50;
  public int getBalance(){
    return balance;
    }
    public void withdraw(int amt){
        balance=balance-amt;
        }
    }
public class AccountBalance implements Runnable {

    private Account acc=new Account();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccountBalance accBal=new AccountBalance();
        Thread one=new Thread(accBal);
        Thread two=new Thread(accBal);
        one.setName("Thread One");
        two.setName("thread Two");
        one.start();
        two.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            makeWithdrawal(10);
        }
    }
    public synchronized void makeWithdrawal(int amount){
        if(acc.getBalance()>=amount){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is going to withdraw "+acc.getBalance());
        try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){}
        acc.withdraw(amount);               //line 1
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" completes the withdrawal");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not enough in account for "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" to withdraw "+acc.getBalance());
        }
    }
}
```

1) Suppose **Thread Fred** enters a synchronized block and get a lock on object **accBal** then somewhere in middle **Thread Fred** call **another method(line 1)** which is not synchronized, then the thread does not releases the lock Why? If thread comes out from synchronized then it should release the lock or it takes the lock till synchronized block.

2) Suppose I have one more method say **changeAccount** which is not synchronized then a new Thread say **Thread Three** which is having the same object **accBal** will enter that method and can change the variable balance which violates our code of synchronization.

So does there is anything that Java provides that even if there is a non-synchronized code and a Thread is having a lock on a object then another Thread should not enter the non-synchronized code with same object means once a lock has taken by Thread then no Thread will act upon that object unless lock is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The thread, although executing code from another method, is still executing the original synchronized method. This other method execution is just a part of the original synchronized method execution.
2. That's correct, any thread any time can change values that are unprotected.
3. There's other ways to perform mutual exclusion (like using a CountDownLatch) but without fully synchronizing your critical sections you can run into multithreaded memory issues like stale values.

Comment: CountDownLatch does _not_ provide mutual exclusion.  In fact, its usual use-case basically is the opposite:  It's used to insure that a group of threads all reach the same point at the same time.

Comment: I don't suggest to use the CountDownLatch as a way to provide mutual exclusion but I'm saying that it could be potentially used in a not so good way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Suppose Thread Fred enters a synchronized block and get a lock on object accBal then somewhere in middle Thread Fred call another method(line 1) which is not synchronized, then the thread does not releases the lock Why?

Consider the following code

```
synchronized (accBal) {
    method()
}
// this line has to be reached before the lock on accBal is released
```

When method() is invoked, it does not exit the synchronized block, the synchronized block is 'pushed' on a stack and retained for when the call to `method()` returns (exits).  Thus the lock is not released during the call to method().

> 2) Suppose I have one more method say changeAccount which is not synchronized then a new Thread say Thread Three which is having the same object accBal will enter that method and can change the variable balance which violates our code of synchronization.

Correct.  It would violate the synchronization, and the behaviour would be a little tricky to predict and the visibility of any data changes between the threads would be prone to data races and side effects of under the hood optimisations.  Thus it is important that everybody honors the synchronized block.

> 3) So does there is anything that Java provides that even if there is a non-synchronized code and a Thread is having a lock on a object then another Thread should not enter the non-synchronized code with same object means once a lock has taken by Thread then no Thread will act upon that object unless lock is released.

In Java, all pessimistic forms of locking require every thread to play nice with each other and to check the locks.  The rationale being that there is a cost to performing concurrency checks, and most code does not require those overheads.

Answer (score 1):

1. A synchronized block only releases the lock when it exits.  There is no really good reason *why* this is the case and you are not bound to it if your logic is able to cope with the member variables changing as you progress through the method.  Use a ReadWrite lock (probably ReentrantReadWriteLock) and research the patterns that these provide.
2. If you sometimes access member variables with locks and sometimes without, then you should probably not have them at all.  Certainly, a product like SONAR would flag this pattern with a big red sign.  Again, you probably want to use a fine-grained approach using ReadWriteLock.

Comment: There is a _very_ good reason why `synchronized(lock){foo(); bar();}` does not give up the lock inside the foo() call, and then give it up again inside the bar() call.  What if foo() starts an operation that temporarily puts some data structure into a state that other threads must not be allowed to see, and then bar() completes the operation, and makes things safe again?  How could you ever synchronize that if there was no way to hold a lock for the duration of both calls?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you have a method which accesses data that should be protected, that method (or the critical code within it) should be synchronized (on the same object). If you leave the method unsynchronized, it means that the programmer believes that the data it accesses does not need protection.

You can have other methods of locking, but there is nothing that will make Java lock what the programmer did not consider worth locking. Locking carries a performance penalty, so unprotected code (that the programmer considered safe) should not be automatically protected.